# Converting PHP dependent SQL code to full SQL

Tags: php, mysql

the question will require a bit long of an answer to explain due to my ignorance on SQL. 
I hope it will not be viewed as vague because I have tried doing it by parts, but then I wont know which part exactly is causing which problem.(It really shows my level of knowledge on SQL.)

I have a code that was originally written in a PHP file, but I have decided I want to create a view table in order for the page to load faster. 
The reason was because it does a loop to list the ranking of students and was taking too long for the web page to load.

Anyways, here is the code :

```
    SELECT
      SUM(VCA.meritPoint) AS merit,
      VCA.student_no      AS student_no,
      P.program_code      AS education_level,
      P.name              AS name,
      P.gender            AS gender,
      P.campus_id         AS campus_id
    FROM viewcardactivity VCA
      JOIN pupil P ON P.student_no = VCA.student_no
      JOIN semester S ON S.id = '{$id}' -- MAX() AND (MAX() - 1)
        AND DATE(VCA.tarikh) BETWEEN DATE(s.tarikhStart) AND DATE(s.tarikhEnd)
          WHERE P.campus_id = '{$campus}' -- 1, 2
            AND P.gender= '{$gender}' -- M, F
            AND VCA.level= '{$level}' -- Diploma, Degree
            AND P.program_code = (CONVERT(IF((SUBSTR(REPLACE(`p`.`program_code`,' ',''),3,1) = 1),'Diploma','Degree')USING latin1))
    GROUP BY student_no ORDER BY merit DESC
```

As the name of the columns suggests, I would like to display more than one instead of specific ids, gender and level provided from the PHP variables.

The example output I would like to have is such as(based on the SQL Fiddle mock data :

```
table 'viewrankingmerit'   
| merit | student_no | education_level | name | gender | campus_id | 
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|  99   | 111111111  |      Diploma    | Ash  |   M    |     1     | 
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|  87   | 222222222  |      Diploma    |Belle |   F    |     1     | 
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|  85   | 333333333  |      Degree     | Carl |   M    |     1     | 
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|  80   | 444444444  |      Degree     | Deli |   F    |     1     | 
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|  75   | 555555555  |      Diploma    | Eddy |   M    |     2     | 
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|  74   | 666666666  |      Diploma    |Foxxy |   F    |     2     | 
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|  50   | 777777777  |      Degree     | Greg |   M    |     2     | 
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|  20   | 888888888  |      Degree     |Haley |   F    |     2     | 
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As for the semester id, I would like to get the latest 2 ids. Which is the highest and second highest, based on the auto-generated id that will keep on increasing..

I was immediately stuck at trying to get 2 ids from table semester. I've tried using :

```
JOIN semester S1 ON S1.id = (SELECT MAX(s1.id) FROM semester)
   AND DATE(VCA.tarikh) BETWEEN DATE(s1.tarikhStart) AND DATE(s1.tarikhEnd)

JOIN semester S2 ON S2.id = (SELECT MAX(s2.id)-1 FROM semester)
   AND DATE(VKA.tarikh) BETWEEN DATE(s2.tarikhStart) AND DATE(s2.tarikhEnd)
```

It was probably a bad reference, but that was the closest solution I got so far.

1) Is it possible to do a table to show all the info?

2) If yes, how to get both S.id, P.campus_id, P.gender and VCA.level. Hoping that the solution would be alike.

3) If no, what is the best solution?

Thanks a lot guys.

[Edit] I've added a demo data in an [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aee776)

Comment: Look into stored procedures

Comment: Are you using MySQL or (MS) SQL-Server?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I am using MySQL.

Comment: Can you set up a demo of data in an [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) So that way we can help you better.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Done! That took me quite some time since it was my first time. Here : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad6823.

Comment: I saw some problems with your data... First, there is no constraint between the semester table and the viewcardactiviti besides the date, that is a bad design. Also, your semester dates are conflicting with each other is that right? `'2014-11-01', '2015-04-30'` the first ends after the second start `'2015-03-01', '2015-07-31'` ! Also, you have to explain the rules for the filters you added in the query you did, there are comments for it, you mean that you want those two values at same time? And what you mean with `-- MAX AND (MAX - 1)` for the semester? last two? It would be great if you....

Comment: ...provide from that sample data you create what would be the resulting rows from it. That alone will clear up the undestanding. Also what the meaning of this on your query: `P.program_code = (CONVERT(IF((SUBSTR(REPLACE(`p`.`program_code`,' ',''),3,1) = 1),'Diploma','Degree')USING latin1))`

Comment: @JorgeCampos About the design, I can't do much. I am just fiddling with a system that was previously created by someone else. We will create a new system in the far future. It conflicts because it was for different sessions.. I will make a sample output in the question. As for the query, since the current table does not have a column to show the student's education level, I had to read from their program_code to create a column for that. If their number starts from 1 then Diploma, if 2 then Degree.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I have added the output table I would like to have. Thanks for bearing with me.

Comment: You have to fix your data sample (in fiddle) because right now it is impossible to return what you want because there is no link between the pupils with id greater then 555... on the viewcardactiviti table.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Oh my, sorry about that. I've fixed that. Inserted a new link.

Comment: With the provided data it still not possible to reproduce the result you want. But still though I've made a query to you analyse and see if it attends to your need, if it do, I will add as an answer. See here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aee776/3 If not you can say where you think it is wrong.

Comment: @JorgeCampos All is well except the merit points. The highest should be 15. It seems the merit doubled for each of them.

Comment: Thats because the confliting dates on the semesters did you look into that? For instance the `12 - '2015-06-01', '2015-10-30'` and `13, '2015-09-01', '2016-03-30'` So every one that is in between 2016-09-01 and 2015-10-30 will sum twice. For that either you fix the semester period or fix the dates on viewcardactiviti table for each pupil.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Hm.. thought it was possible in SQL too. So if I were to separate it to 2 ranking tables for Diploma and Degree it would be possible? If yes, then I'll gladly accept that as an answer and off my way to finish this system.

Comment: It is, but you have to define the rules to it, like a pupil can be at two type (degree and diploma) but it should sum separateddly. I think this last one is what you need, take a look: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aee776/4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some discussion in coments, this is the final result. I think.

```
select sum(vca.meritPoint)      as merit,
       vca.student_no      AS student_no,
       vca.type            AS education_level,
       p.name              AS name,
       p.gender            AS gender,
       p.campus_id         AS campus_id
 from
   viewcardactiviti vca
      inner join pupil p ON p.student_no = vca.student_no
      inner join (select * from semester order by id desc limit 2) s
              ON (vca.tarikh between s.tarikhStart and s.tarikhEnd
                  AND vca.type = s.level)
group by vca.student_no, vca.type, p.name, p.gender, p.campus_id
order by merit desc, p.campus_id;
```

See it here on [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aee776/4)

If you need to filter for specific configurations like the parameters on your original query just add a `WHERE` clause.

This subquery `(select * from semester order by id desc limit 2)` will get the last to semesters based on the ID. And since there is no direct link (foreign key) between semester and viewcardactiviti you can use there join conditions `ON (vca.tarikh between s.tarikhStart and s.tarikhEnd AND vca.type = s.level)`

If you think that it still need to change anything let me know!

Comment: For the question, this is the closest possible solution. I'll just have to create 2 different tables for the clashing semester dates. It'll be faster to load anyways. Thanks for the great help, I learned a lot from one question. :)